# Spring Security Endpoints unreachable by filter

Tags: spring-security

I have this configuration

```
    httpSecurity
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
        .cors().and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/ping").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .addFilter(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()));
```

If I try to reach `/login` it uses the `AuthenticationFilter` I created, but for other endpoints like `/api/v1/collection/pastDueContact`, it denied the access. But it doesn't use the `AuthenticationFilter` (a custom filter I created) and I need that...

Comment: What is your quesiton?

Comment: how i make my endpoints use the custom filter i create...

Actually it's like my endpoints are not reachable, if i use

/api/v1/collection/pastDueContact

I got an 'access denied' and if i add some string at the end just to try to get a 404 Not Found like:

/api/v1/collection/pastDueContactxxxx

I still get an 'acess denied' which doesn't have any sense...

Comment: Show your implementation of `AuthenticationFilter`.

Comment: I think it doesn't has any relation with that, as for the entry /reports/login it gets into the filter, but for my other endpoints it doesn't..

Comment: dur you were right, my apology, my implementation of AuthenticationFilter was the point, as I was implementing PasswordAuthentication, it only got into it when i try to /login

What i did was create a custom filter extending BasicAuthentication and added to the chain and it worked...